# How to normalize unknown characters in Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I'm using lucene with the following filter chain:

`StandardFilter > LowerCaseFilter > GermanNormalizationFilter > ASCIIFoldingFilter`

Which additional filter do I have to use to convert any unknown characters to the latin alphabet?
Eg russian strings like `Кадашевская`, I would like them to either be converted to the latin alphabet equivalent, or have them removed.

Which filter fits this purpose?

At the moment, the filter chain normalized the string to: `???????????`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe [`ICUTransformFilter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_1/analyzers-icu/org/apache/lucene/analysis/icu/ICUTransformFilter.html) would be a good choice:

```
TokenFilter filter = new ICUTransformFilter(
    previousFilter, 
    Transliterator.getInstance("Cyrillic-Latin")
);
```

I think it's reasonably clear that the idea of transforming every possible character into an equivalent latin character is nonsense (what is the latin equivalent of 锁?  Or ♞?).  However, you can also chain together multiple transformations to hit as many as possible, such as also converting Greek to Latin, and Katakana to Latin:

```
TokenFilter filter = new ICUTransformFilter(
    previousFilter, 
    Transliterator.getInstance("Cyrillic-Latin;Greek-Latin;Katakana-Latin")
);
```

You need to include "lucene-analyzers-icu-4.x.x.jar" for the filter, as well as [download and include ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org/download)